# How to include a parameter of a custom type I declared?

Tags: powershell

[This article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh551144.aspx) says that the parameter declaration must be the first executable line of code in a script.

So then how can I declare a parameter of a custom type that I create?

For e.g. I'd like to create a script like so:

```
param
(
 [MyCustomTypesNamespace.Cat] $myCat
)
```

Should the `Cat` class be declared in the same file *after* the parameter definition?

Or should I have to define the `Cat` class in a separate file and reference that file in here?

Comment: I don't think that will work, and I don't think it needs to. PowerShell scripts are normally invoked from outside PowerShell, so you won't be able to pass `Cat` objects anyway. If this is intended for use in PowerShell only it's probably better to make it a module, put the code in a function, and load the type when the module is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a module or profile loaded that has that type previously.  I would suggest using a function declaration, though.

```
Class Cat { Cat() {} }

Function Action
{
    Param([Cat]$MyCat)
    <# ... #>
}

$BlueCat = [Cat]::New()
Action $BlueCat
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a difference between calling the ctor like `[Cat]::New()` and calling the `New-Object` cmdlet?

Comment: No, there is not a difference.  I don't think versions older than v5 support the new convention, though (`[Cat]::New()`) @WaterCoolerv2

Comment: Thank you. You're right. Classes, interfaces, polymorphism, etc. were added in v5.